# jQuery UI Modal Popup Window on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to run some examples from Jquery site and some videos i' ve seen, but it seems like i can't execute them properly. Here's my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#btnclick").click(function() {
                    $("#divpopup").dialog({
                        title: "blabla",
                        width: 430,
                        height: 200,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            Close:
                            function() {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divpopup" style="display:none">
        blablablabla
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="btnclick">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't find what's wrong, the only thing it may be is that i haven't input an important library or something. Every one of my explorers shows me the button, but clicking it doesn't trigger the modal window. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery library references should be in below order.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user2010686, jquery library should be referenced first. Then only jquery ui reference should be added.